# Need to extract value from UI using Xpath - using Taiko framework

Tags: xpath, textbox, taiko

Am trying to extract value from the field. I can use only Xpath to identify the field.
tried
$(xpath).text() - i think since am tring to extract vale it returned 0
$(xpath).value() - did not work
textBox().value() - inside text box am able to pass id, name. but i need to pass xpath to get the value.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [evaluate](https://docs.taiko.dev/api/evaluate/) api to return the value.